# How does L1 Loss work in lightGBM

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, xgboost, gbm, lightgbm

From the [paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/6907-lightgbm-a-highly-efficient-gradient-boosting-decision-tree.pdf), lightGBM does a subsampling according to sorted $|g_i|$, where $g_i$ is the gradient (for the loss function) at a data instance.

My question is that, when the objective is L1 loss/regularization, $loss_i = |y_i - \hat{y_i}|$, hence $g_i$ is either 1 or -1 (assume no zero loss). Therefore the absolute value of gradient is 1 for any data instance. How to sort then and select instances for the subsample? Or does lightGBM skip the subsampling process if L1 regularization is selected?

Comment: First, L1 loss and L1 regularization are quite different; your question seems to make sense for L1 loss.  I don't know the answer, but these might be helpful:  
https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/462612b42c6fe7bb1be1ccd8b72d77021b9f2d38/src/boosting/goss.hpp  
https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/979  
https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/pull/1199

Comment: Also possibly relevant: http://nicolas-hug.com/blog/around_gradient_boosting#line-search-for-least-absolute-deviation-loss